# Show that the integrals are equivalent

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Show that:

$$\int_o^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{1+x}dx=\int_o^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{(1+x)^2}dx$$

I have no idea how to approach. The only thing I can think is substitution $y=\pi/2-x$ or integration by parts but am unable to obtain other side from one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**:We integrate by parts
$$\int_0^{A}\frac{\cos(x)}{1+x}dx=\left[\frac{\sin x}{1+x}\right]_0^A+\int_0^{A}\frac{\sin(x)}{(1+x)^2}dx$$
then we pass to limit $A\to \infty$ with the fact $|\sin x|\leq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\cos{x}}{1+x}\,dx=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{d(\sin{x})}{1+x},$$
then integrate it by parts.